# Is Alt+L blocked in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to create shortcuts for a website and for some reason Alt+L isn't working in Chrome (33.0.1750.117 m). I tried checking in Firefox (27.0.1) and it worked just fine.

I'm just trying to do a basic hook:

```
$(window).on("keydown", function(e) {
   if (e.altKey == true && e.which == 76) alert("no alerts");
});
```

[Fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Chakra/4CVJq/)

For me, Alt+L doesn't create an update at all, but L alone does as well as Alt+.

I tried Googling around for an answer but I wasn't getting anything helpful. Is this a browser quirk or something specific with my setup?

Comment: I'd have to press alt, release it, then press L. I can't detect any L keydown event if alt is already down.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not blocked

Look [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en) official page

alt + L is not used for anything

Answer (score 0):

Whoops. Looks like I had an extension (Prime Player) that hijacked Alt+L completely. Disabled the shortcut within the Extensions -> Keyboard shortcuts page and everything works again.